# Salesforce: environment-specific variable replacement in a custom button url

Tags: salesforce

I have a custom Salesforce (Summer '11) button.  Clicking the button navigates the user to a url in a new window.  The url points to my own custom web app.  (It does not point to the same url as that of the salesforce environment).

I want this url to be configurable for my dev, staging and live environments, so that the button in the SalesForce dev environment points to the app's dev environment, and so on.

If possible, what's the best way to achieve this, given that I'll be deploying the customization in dev (inc. button, but other things too) via a changeset which I'll push to the staging and live environments?

Comment: You would want to implement this using a custom setting. Sadly it's not yet? possible - we need to vote: http://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000I5NsAAK

Comment: @sorenkrabbe Thanks - this deserves an upvote (and possibly an acceptance) if you could repost it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks. Though I'd much rather like the idea on IdeaExchange to receive upvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to implement this using a custom setting. Sadly it's not yet? possible - we need to vote: success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000I5NsAAK

Answer (score 0):

As long as your button URL is pointing to a relative path rather than the full path including the server instance (and, of course, as long as the path exists) your button will work across server instances without any fuss.

For example, do: `/{!Account.Id}/e? etc.`

do not: `https://eu1.salesforce.com/{!Account.Id}/e? etc.`

Comment: Thanks, but the url I'm trying to make configurable would always be a different domain to that of the salesforce url.  The web app in question is completely separate to salesforce.